# Replacement for ng-keyup on mobile devices

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I'm using Controller As syntax and clearly ng-keyup="vm.someFunction()" is not working for mobile device, while works for desktops.

What could be the replacement for "ng-keyup" for mobile devices, to invoke a  function on key up.

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="vm.pinCode" ng-keyup="vm.pinCodeEntered()" />
```

I've tried ng-change aswell but still not working

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you should try `ng-change`

Comment: @Akashii 
Thanks for the suggestion but ng-change didn't work.
Would you like to suggest something else?